# Как добавить строку в таблицу (MySql INSERT)?

Tags: mysql

Существует таблица с полями id, field1, field2, необходимо добавить строку в таблицу при условии, что добавляемое значение не существует в field2. field2 не уникальное.

**Добавлено:**

```
INSERT INTO t_test (field2) SELECT 'value' FROM t_test WHERE field2 = 'value' HAVING COUNT(*) = 0
```

ничего умней пока не придумал...

Comment: А как так, что-то не догоняю. field2 не уникальное, но добавление происходит только если не совпадает с field2. Значит все-таки оно уникальное?

Comment: допустим field2 имеет значения: a,a,a,b,b,c если посылаем к примеру a то не добавляется строка, если же d то добавить

Comment: Читайте документацию, не ленитесь.

Comment: потому и спрашиваю, что прочитав документацию, этот запрос единственное что смог вынести.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то попробуйте сначала просто провести проверку. К примеру:

```
$q=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sometable` WHERE `field2`='{$INPUTDATA}'"));
if($q['field2']!=false){mysql_query("INSERT INTO ...");}
```

Comment: да, понимаю с помощью php это решается на раз ) но необходимо именно запросом, желательно одним.

Comment: Состояние гонки. Два процесса одновременно начали выборку, обоим `SELECT` вернул пустоту (вообще, надо было бы `COUNT(*)` и 0 ловить), оба вставили.

Поэтому `SELECT FOR UPDATE` (чтобы заблокировать ряды) и все обернуть в транзакцию (`BEGIN`...`COMMIT`). Вроде бы.

Answer (score 3):

На [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql/3025332#3025332) предложили такую идею:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (value1, value2) 
SELECT 'stuff for value1', 'stuff for value2' FROM `table` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `table` 
                  WHERE value1='stuff for value1' AND value2='stuff for value2') 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Кстати, отличный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` ...
```

не сработает?

Comment: к сожалению нет. он опирается на индекс, а field2 таковым не является.

Comment: Тогда нужно почитать синтаксис IF THEN или 
    INSERT .... WHERE NOT EXIST

я сам не силен в этих запросах))